# How to resolve the deployment issue in Visual studio?

Tags: add-in

> I have created an Add-in for MS Word using Visual studio. When i deploy and install that in other machine i get the following error message.*

**Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for Sample or its location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.**

> But i can able to install this add-in in few machines. Any idea why does this happen?*

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this problem.

This problem occurs due to security level of the system. When we download the zip file from the internet, its contents are blocked in our system for security reasons. So the setup was not installed in other systems. We need to unblock the zip file (right click on zip file and press the unblock button). Now extract the contents of the zip file and try installing the setup file.